# <video> element and subtitles - Display weirdly

Tags: css, html5-video, bootstrap-modal, subtitle

**EDIT**: I was able to recreate the issue in Codepen, with two identical video elements (and tracks), one on the page and one accessible in a modal. Unfortunately, the cc box doesn't appear at all in the modal:
https://codepen.io/SarahF3000/pen/Rxyjgb

---

I use a video element to present **audio interview**, to include subtitles.
So I shorted the height (100px) of the video element.

But it seems there are issues to choose the languages of the subtitles (English, French or Macedonian), **the box opening from the CC button doesn't display well**, and so are the languages options (we can't click easily on it).

Here is how it appears [in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x68Dr.png) and [in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrUBR.png).

And here is the HTML code:

```
<video controlsList="nodownload" controls>
  <source type="audio/mp3" src="skopje/volhan/volhan1.mp3">
  <track label="English" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="skopje/volhan/v1en.vtt" default>
  <track label="French" kind="subtitles" srclang="fr" src="skopje/volhan/v1fr.vtt">
  <track label="Macedonian" kind="subtitles" srclang="mk" src="skopje/volhan/v1mk.vtt">
</video>
```

And the CSS code:

```
video {
    object-fit: initial;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: -5px;
}

::cue {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

Do you know if there is a way to make the CC box appears well?

Thank you very much!

EDIT: I noticed it's linked to the fact that the page is **responsive**: the video player is **inside a bootstrap modal** and the "CC box" is always at a certain position of the page: [with a 1413px large page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvIET.png) and [with a 1016px large page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI8KE.png). But I still don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Posto your code, without is impossible to understand where is the problem.

Comment: Yes indeed, sorry I just edited my post :)

Comment: Probably something in bootstrap override your code or browser default. Try without bootstrap.

Comment: Hi @GermanoPlebani and thank you for your answer. Unfortunately in this case I need to put it in a bootstrap modal.

Comment: OK, but without modal the issue persist?

Comment: I've got some more help and we figured out that the issue is just in Chrome. Chrome set a position for the cc box before that the modal is positioned, so it's misplaced.
The issue can be see here also https://codepen.io/SarahF3000/pen/Rxyjgb

When we remove the .modal-dialog class, there is no problem, but we can't use the close button then.